# Shopify Theme Development - jQuery unable to find sibling child element

Tags: jquery, replace, children, siblings

I am trying to swap the image extension on hover of a sibling anchor, to add an animation on hover of a link. I can't seem to collect the correct element to swap replace the image extension type.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var categoryLinks = $('.category-link');

    if ( categoryLinks.length ) {

        categoryLinks.each(function(){

            var categoryIcon = $(this).siblings('.a-category-icon').children('.category-icon');

            $(this).hover(function() {

                src = categoryIcon.src.replace('.png','.gif' );
                console.log(src);
                categoryIcon.attr('src', src);
                console.log(categoryIcon.src);

            }, function() {

                src = categoryIcon.src.replace('.gif','.png' );
                console.log(src);
                categoryIcon.attr('src', src);
                console.log(categoryIcon.src);

            });
        });
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-inner">

    <div class="categories-container">
        <h3 class="categories-title">Know what you’re looking for?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Molecule.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Chemicals &amp; Standards
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Lab.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Lab Consumables &amp; Supplies
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Equipment.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Equipment &amp; Instruments
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Materials.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Research &amp; Development Materials
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Custom.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Custom Products &amp; Services
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error on hover:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js?703:23)

at HTMLAnchorElement.handle (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)

at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)

at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)
```

Error on end of hover:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js?703:30)

at HTMLAnchorElement.handle (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)

at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)

at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-v3-4-1.js?703:2)
```

Where the errors refer to the lines:

```
src = categoryIcon.src.replace('.png','.gif' );
```

And:

```
src = categoryIcon.src.replace('.gif','.png' );
```

What is the source of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // get all the category links
  var categoryLinks = $('.category-link');
  // category links exists?
  if (categoryLinks.length) {
    // loop through every category link
    categoryLinks.each(function(){
      // "cache" the current link object
      var link = $(this);
      // get the siblings' category icon
      var categoryIcon = link.siblings('.a-category-icon').children('.category-icon');
      
      // on hover of the current link
      link.hover(function() {
        // get the src property of the category icon and replace .png with .gif
        var src = categoryIcon.prop('src').replace('.png','.gif' );
        // set src property of the category icon
        categoryIcon.prop('src', src);
      }, function() {
        // get the src property of the category icon and replace .gif with .png
        var src = categoryIcon.prop('src').replace('.gif','.png' );
        // set src property of the category icon
        categoryIcon.prop('src', src);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.a-category {
  position: relative;
}
a.category-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-inner">

    <div class="categories-container">
        <h3 class="categories-title">Know what you’re looking for?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Molecule.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Chemicals &amp; Standards
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Lab.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Lab Consumables &amp; Supplies
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Equipment.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Equipment &amp; Instruments
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Materials.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Research &amp; Development Materials
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="a-category">
        <a class="category-link box-link" href="/"></a>

        <div class="a-category-icon">
            <img class="category-icon" alt="Category Icon" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/Custom.png?v=1565789686">
        </div>
        <div class="a-category-content">
            <div class="category-title">
                Custom Products &amp; Services
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the amends to my question, much neater. Also very good stab at the answer, can you adjust it to work on the hover of the anchor link, not the icon itself please? NOTE: the anchor is an absolutely positioned element that sits as a sibling to the container of the icon.

Comment: @JasonIsMyName Done.

Comment: That is brilliant, just for brownie points. Can you explain a little as to why you have had to create a variable link = $this and your use of .prop . I know what they are and how they are used but as to why they have had to be swapped in in this instance would be really nice.

Comment: @JasonIsMyName Just added some comments. The `link = $(this)` isn't necessary, but it's better  so that you only create the object once and use it twice later on.